# How to use middleclick scrolling (smooth scrolling) in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, scrolling

I am trying to use middleclick scrolling or in it's other name smooth scrolling in Ubuntu 22.04.

I click down the mouse wheel button and try to scroll up or down but nothing happens.

I tried to check the system mouse options but there is no button there to toggle ON/OFF middleclick scrolling / smooth scrolling.

How to use middleclick scrolling (smooth scrolling) in Ubuntu?

Comment: Specific app or just any random app?

Comment: @user1686 any random app...

Comment: These answers might help, so try them : [answer`](https://askubuntu.com/a/49421/963426) and [answer2](https://askubuntu.com/a/1391464/963426).

Answer (score 0):

Most GTK and Qt programs **do not support** middle-button scrolling. (Neither do most Windows programs, for that matter.) You'll find it only in specific apps, such as Firefox or LibreOffice.

(For Firefox, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/908/firefox-middle-mouse-button-scroll)

For everything else, use the scrollbar.

(Also, this usage of middle-button somewhat conflicts with "paste current *selection*" which traditionally is assigned to the middle mouse button in X11 – so when it comes to text input fields, most Linux programs choose to implement "paste selection" rather than "autoscroll".)

Comment: Hello and thank you. In LibreOffice in Ubuntu it didn't work for me. In Windows it work anywhere as I can remember...

Comment: Furthermore, my personal browser is Chrome, sadly I didn't find where to toggle middleclick scrolling in its menu.